# Can't Select All Files on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and other anomalies, need your help ASAP

Tags: shortcut-keys

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and a lot of weird things start to happen including:
**1.** Files from my previous OS (xubuntu) were not deleted, although i've deleted and created new partitions while installing Ubuntu 20.04
and
**2.** I can't select all files or all folders on Desktop! I can do it within folders but I can't use for example Ctrl + A on desktop, I can't even select all the files with a cursor, it only selects one!
Please help me.